# Making voice calls from Android phone connected to Linux

Tags: android, linux, adb, android-phone-call

I have an Andorid phone connected to a Linux server. I need a bash script to use the phone to dial a number and read out a string when the call is answered.

I have ADB installed on the Linux server and the following code works fine for dialling a number:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:$phone_number
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxx }
```

However I am not sure how to get it to read a string and then disconnect the call. Is there a text to speech for ADB/Android that could help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that it is almost impossible to play a voice during the call due to security restrictions on Android.

Answer (score 0):

```
adb shell input keyevent 6
```

this adb command will hang up the call. Try the command.

Answer (score 0):

#### I have a such feature in one of my adb tools, maybe this will give you a hint :

```
#!/bin/bash
LANDSCODE="+<landscode here>"

   trap ctrl_c INT

   function ctrl_c() {
           echo "Aborted call.."
           adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ENDCALL
           exit
   }

   read -p "Enter Number: $LANDSCODE" number
   if [[ -z $number ]]; then
      echo "You must enter a phone number, aborted.."
      exit      
   elif [[ $(echo $number | wc -c) -lt 7 ]]; then
      echo "This is not a real number, enter a real number.."
      exit
   else
   read -p "Do you want speaker on (y/n): " speaker
   case $speaker in
              "y") 
                   adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:$LANDSCODE$number &> /dev/null; 
                   sleep 2.0;
                   adb shell service call audio 20 i32 1 # does this really works on android oreo 8.0?
                     echo "Dialing +$LANDSCODE$number"
                     read -p "Press any key to end call"
                   adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ENDCALL
                     echo -e "Call ended"
                   adb shell input keyevent 6
                   exit 1 ;;
              "n") 
                   adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:$LANDSCODE$number &> /dev/null
                     echo -e "Dialing $LANDSCODE$number"
                   read -p "Press any key to end call"
                   adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ENDCALL
                     echo "Call ended"
                   adb shell input keyevent 6
                   exit 1 ;;
   esac
   fi
```